# Unable to change country in Exchange Admin center 2016, but can in AD

Tags: active-directory, permissions, mailbox, attributes, exchange-2016

I have started having an issue when trying to change a user/mailboxes country/region through Exchange Admin Center in Exchange 2016.

When attempting to do so, I get this error:

```
Active Directory operation failed on DC. This error is not retriable. Additional information: Insufficient access rights to perform the operation.
Active Directory response: 00002098: SecErr: DSIS-03150E49, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0
```

Other reports of this error do not seem to have a resolution that applies to us. Oddly, If I go into ADUC, and find the same user account, I can easily change the country/region using my same domain login (member of domain admins and enterprise admins).

Does anyone have any thoughts on why I can change this attribute directly through AD but not Exchange?

EDIT:
Also have this post on the TechNet forum trying to identify the cause of this issue:
[Technet Post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/719dd951-9d6c-4f2d-b3ac-d20317f6e38e/unable-to-modify-a-recipients-location-through-ecp-but-can-through-aduc?forum=exchange2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was found with some assistance from Allen on the technet forum [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0853854b-4276-4451-be40-7df3eeebfb43/unable-to-change-country-of-remote-mailbox-through-ecp?forum=Exch2016Adm)

User object security inheritance seems to be disabled for many of our user objects, while newly created objects have it enabled, and can be edited through ECP.